# Nodejs Puppeteer Object undefined after function

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to do a webScraping application, but when initializing browser and page objects, they are undefined after returned from `init()` function. Here's a snippet:

Browser and Page are initialized at the top of my file: with `browser = null`  and `page = null`
so i want to use these globals in my `init()` function.

```
async function init() {
try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      args: ["--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
  return {
    first: page,
    second: browser,
  };
}
var retvals = init();
browser = retvals.browser;
page = retvals.page;
console.log(typeof browser);
console.log(typeof page);

scrapeSite(urls[0]);
```

How can i solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what if you put console log  after this line: "page = await browser.newPage();" before catch, what did you get ?

Comment: @sohaieb both of type object there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return this object from `init()`:

```
{
  first: page,
  second: browser,
}
```

but you use it like this:

```js
var retvals = init();
browser = retvals.browser;
page = retvals.page;
```

you should use it like this:

```js
var retvals = await init();
browser = retvals.second;
page = retvals.first;
```

But I do recommend renaming those object keys since it's confusing (even to you now).

Also note that you made `init()` an async function. Every async function returns a promise, so:

```js
console.log(typeof browser);
console.log(typeof page);
```

is executed before the promise is resolved, that's why these are undefined. So you need to use some way of dealing with asynchronous code, e.g. awaiting `init()`.

Comment: it remains undefined.. I remember trying this aswell, but still not working.

Comment: One thing I missed: `init()` is an async function, so it returns a promise. You need to await it or use `.then()`. I updated my answer.